# Moving kitchen into dining room

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I have recently purchased a 1930's very typical London terraced house- little rectangular kitchen at the back next to a formal separate dining room. I have attached the floorplan. I am going to build the wall back up between the reception room and dining room and reinstate the door and then knock down the wall between the dining room and kitchen. My plan has always been for a open plan kitchen diner and I would ideally love to put the kitchen on the far left wall in the dining room and turn the existing kitchen area into a space for my table. This would open it up a lot and be more usable. I also want to put a conservatory on the back of the dining room. The drain is located under the kitchen window (next to where the existing sink is) So my eventual question is what do you think the problems I may encounter are? Would it be mainly around drainage? I have yet to get any quotes just would like to approach the professionals with more of an idea!! Thanks everyone  [image: Floor plan]

Comment: What is below this -- do you have access to pipes underneath? Have you considered removing the wall between kitchen and dining room? If it's [tag:load-bearing] you'll have to get an engineer to design a beam and a professional to install it (replacing load-bearing walls is not a DIY job); if not, it's relatively simple to remove (though you may have to relocate some electrical, plumbing and/or HVAC runs). This will give you the 'open concept' and allow you to keep most of the kitchen more or less where it is. Worth costing both options out, anyway.

Comment: Thank you- yes I will be removing that wall too- the kitchen area is really pokey and although it looks like it will be all large and open plan I don't think it will have the same affect as moving the kitchen. But it is at least a nice alternative if moving the kitchen isn't doable. There are floor boards throughout the house so Id imagine there is easy access to any pipes? Yes Ill most certainly get a professional in to remove the wall, my talents lie in painting and soft furnishing!!

Comment: Did you do this? What was the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts, in no particular order:

Where's the water heater? The longer the pipe run between it and the kitchen, the longer you'll be waiting for hot water. There are instant hot water devices if this is an issue.

The oven will presumably need either an electrical or gas connection.

You're putting the dining table directly under the toilet. How's the sound insulation?

Is the wall you'd be knocking down load-bearing?

Comment: The boiler is being installed next week and its going to be located in bedroom 2 in the top left hand cupboard so almost directly above where I would like the kitchen to be (if that's what you mean by water heater?) The water pipes are also going to run straight down from the boiler too (Im getting central heating put in next week as I currently have warm air heating)

Comment: I have a old gas cooker in the current kitchen but I can easily have electric to save the connection of gas into the dining room if that will work? Im also getting the house rewired at the same time next week so all the wiring will be new. Ive not told my electrician to set up the electrics for an electric cooker here as I wasn't sure if this kitchen move could be possible but I could ask him? The sound from the loo should be ok and yes the knockable wall is load bearing but my folks did this to their very very similar house so Im not too worried about that :)

Comment: Yeah, boiler=hot water heater. Placing it above the kitchen should be fine. Electric vs gas isn't that different, it's just running a cable vs running tubing, just a reminder. Figure out if you prefer electric or gas cooking, then act accordingly. I find the removal of a load-bearing wall dubious, though.

Comment: Don't the builders just add an RSJ? (If that's even what its called?!!) I thought people knocked down these 1930s kitchen walls all the time? Most of the houses on my road have done it I would say.Thanks though Ill have a chat with both my plumber and electrician about it and see if theres any work to do now. I think Ill get some builders in this week so they can tell me if its doable. You have to plan 18 steps ahead with a renovation hey!!!

Comment: Yeah, if the builder says it's ok, you should be fine. Be sure to mention the boiler placement. Water is heavy.